# Passing a list of arguments to plot in R

Tags: r, list, plot

I would like to use the same arguments for several calls to `plot`.
I tried to use a list (which can serve as a dictionary) :

```
a <- list(type="o",ylab="")
plot(x,y, a)
```

But it does not work :

```
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plot type
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending @baptiste's answer, you can use `do.call` like this:

```
x <- 1:10  # some data
y <- 10:1
do.call("plot", list(x,y, type="o", ylab=""))
```

Or setting the arguments in a list and call it `a`

```
a <- list(x,y, type="o", ylab="")
do.call(plot, a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create a function wrapper:

```
myplot <- function(...) plot(...,type="o",ylab="")
myplot(x,y)
```